# Why doesn't the content script open a new window using the windows.create method of the JavaScript APIs for WebExtensions to develop Firefox add-ons?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions, add-on

I'm learning [add-ons (browser extensions) development for Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions). I want to create an add-on that lets the user open a new Firefox window containing multiple tabs when he/she presses a keyboard key combination. I'm using [`windows.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create), since it seems to be the perfect choice. Currently, my `manifest.json` file is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["test.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and the `test.js` file is:

```
(function () {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.code === "KeyU") {

            alert("A");

            function onCreated(windowInfo) {
                alert(`Created window: ${windowInfo.id}`);
            }

            function onError(error) {
                alert(`Error: ${error}`);
            }

            let creating = browser.windows.create({
                url: ["https://translate.google.com/"]
            });

            creating.then(onCreated, onError);

            alert("C");

        }
    });
})();
```

However, it doesn't work. `alert("A");` shows a popup, while `alert("C");` doesn't. The error is clearly in the middle, among those `browser.windows.create` lines, but I'm not able to figure out what's wrong. I'm following the [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create#examples) from Firefox docs.

Answer (score 0):

The `browser.windows` API is not available in content scripts, it's only in  background scripts. There is only a [very limited set of APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#webextension_apis) directly available to content scripts.

Comment: I see, thanks. Would you be so kind to improve your answer providing me an example of implementation?